# Automatically restart Raspberry Pi on Shutdown

Tags: ssh, power, reboot

I'm currently using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ at a remote location and use a VPN and SSH to access the device. If the power unexpectedly goes out at this remote location (or more commonly I stupidly shutdown instead of rebooting), all communications with my Raspberry Pi are gone until I physically go to the device, unplug, and plug the Pi back in.

Is there a solution (short of buying a smart plug, powering off, and powering on again remotely) of restarting the Raspberry Pi **immediately** after it has been powered off?

Comment: Ideally you feed the PI with batteries, and use the electric power to charge them.
Like a nobreack

Comment: `If the power unexpectedly goes out at this remote location` ... wouldn't the pi come back up when power is restored? So really, the only scenario you need to deal with is you using shutdown instead of restart